# User-defined cast to string in C++ (like __repr__ in Python)

Tags: c++, casting

How do I make something like user-defined `__repr__` in Python?

Let's say I have an `object1` of `SomeClass`, let's say I have a function `void function1(std::string)`. Is there a way to define something (function, method, ...) to make compiler cast class SomeClass to `std::string` upon call of `function1(object1)`?

(I know that I can use stringstream buffer and operator <<, but I'd like to find a way without an intermediary operation like that)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define a conversion operator:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    operator std::string () const {
        return "SomeClassStringRepresentation";
    }
};
```

Note that this will work not only in function calls, but in any context the compiler would try to match the type with `std::string` - in initializations and assignments, operators, etc. So be careful with that, as it is all too easy to make the code hard to read with many implicit conversions.

Comment: Be careful: While `__repr__` might be idiomatic Python, the above most definitely is not idiomatic C++ and will confuse the heck out of readers of the code if not used judiciously.

Comment: EDIT: Pavel's answer is of course completely correct, it's the mention of `__repr__` that sounded my warning siren :)

Comment: In C++11, you can use `explicit` in conversion functions, therefore it cannot be used for implicit conversions. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Answer (score 7):

Use a conversion operator. Like this:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    operator string() const { //implement code that will produce an instance of string and return it here}
};
```